# MAMP Pro cannot remove Virtual host

Tags: mamp

Hi I set a virtual host on Mamp Pro so I could work on my website locally, however after I remove that virtual host from the Mamp Pro Gui I can not login back to my site online. The domain remains pointing to localhost 127.0.0.1, any idea how I can regain access to my online site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your /private/etc/hosts file and remove the domain names you don't want pointing to your local server any more.

Comment: Where can I find the hosts file? ^__^

Comment: open terminal. type sudo vim /private/etc/hosts and edit the file.